# HSQLDB (in-mem mode) & Hibernate - DB not updating

Tags: hibernate, hsqldb, in-memory-database

I have followed the steps ,for setting up HSQLDB and Hibernate. Now created one small user details entity class. and created hibernate.cfg file, given my entity class addr. the program executed correctly but when I open the db , the details are not updated.

This is first time m wrkin with im-mem database , really struggling to understand how it works.

just not able to understand whts gng wrong here...

I am starting the server from with eclipse lib folder(where i have added the hsqldb jar)

then executing the main class , no error or exception is shown, able to see the sql query in the console. but nothing in the db

my hibernate.cfg is as below

```
<hibernate-configuration>
<session-factory>
    <!-- Database connection settings -->
    <property name="connection.driver_class">org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver</property>
    <property name="connection.url">jdbc:hsqldb:mem:testdb</property>
    <property name="connection.username">java</property>
    <property name="connection.password"></property>

    <!-- JDBC connection pool (use the built-in) -->
    <property name="connection.pool_size">10</property>

    <!-- SQL dialect -->
    <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect</property>

    <!-- Enable Hibernate's current session context -->
    <property name="current_session_context_class">org.hibernate.context.ManagedSessionContext</property>

    <property name="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache">false</property>
    <property name="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache">false</property>

    <!-- Disable the second-level cache  -->
    <property name="cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheProvider</property>        
    <!-- Echo all executed SQL to stdout -->
    <property name="show_sql">true</property>

    <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">create</property> 

    <!-- the annotated entity class -->
    <mapping class = "com.javaapp.addressbook.dto.UserDetails"/>

</session-factory>
```

eclipse snapshot is attached

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4):

You are connecting to an in-memory database which is stored in your application's process:

```
<property name="connection.url">jdbc:hsqldb:mem:testdb</property>
```

If you want to connect to the database served by the HSQLDB server, then your URL should look like this:

```
<property name="connection.url">jdbc:hsqldb:hsql://localhost/testdb</property>
```

The actual URL depends on how you configured the server.

Comment: thanks for the reply I have to configure my db as in-mem db. I am using the first URL now how can I view that data which is stored in my db, ths the trouble. when I open the server db mngr with similar url, it does not show me my data. Neither m getting any err or exception while running the prog... Please help

Comment: Use the second type of URL from your program.